# Ошибка при попытке авторизоваться вконтакте

Tags: c#, .net, vknet

В строчке, которую я отметил(...............) вылезает ошибка: "Access denied: no access to call this method", хотя settings стоит all. В чем проблема?

```
VkApi api = new VkApi();
        api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()
        {
            Login = "8970",
            Password = "13",
            ApplicationId = 6945,
            Settings = Settings.All
        });
        var dialogs = api.Messages.GetConversations(new GetConversationsParams()); ..................................
        var messages = api.Messages.GetHistory(new MessagesGetHistoryParams()
        { PeerId = dialogs.Items[0].Conversation.Peer.Id });
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вконтакте официально ограничивают доступ к API сообщений, поэтому вы получаете такую ошибку. Чтобы воспользоваться методами для работы с сообщениями, нужно обратиться в поддержку ВК: https://vk.com/dev/messages_api

Если будут ещё какие-либо вопросы по библиотеке, то лучше их задать в телеграмм-чате: https://t.me/VkDotNet

Comment: Да кто же Вам такое сказал? «API сообщений» цветёт и пахнёт и не думает закрываться

Comment: @Kir_Antipov стоит разобраться в ситуации, не правда ли? На своём сайте, они предоставляют информацию об ограничении доступа к api сообщений. Моя формулировка ответа немного искажает суть, в чём я виноват. Но главная мысль в том, что вы должны обратиться в поддержку прежде чем использовать сообщения в своём приложении: https://vk.com/dev/messages_api

Comment: Это уже другой разговор, так и стоило написать в ответе)